# Return a SQLConnection.Open() Method from a function

Tags: c#, database-connection

I am creating a SQL Connection script that is separated into functions and I would like to know if it is possible to return a SQL Connection method from a function. I have already tried and override method but I don't think it is possible, my code is as follows.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace SHCWebsite.App_Code
{
    public class DBConnection
    {
        public static Dictionary<int,Dictionary<string, string>> DBQuery(string tableName, string SQLColQuery, string SQLSpecialReq, string WRAccess, string dbName)
        {
            // create all the needed variables
            var results = "";
            Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>> result = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>>;

            // create a new object called dbConn, init the connection
            object dbConn = InitDBConnection(dbName, WRAccess);

            // return results
            return result;
        }

        protected static object InitDBConnection(string dbName, string WRAccess)
        {
            // setup the database connection
            SqlConnection dbConn = new SqlConnection(
                "Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;"+
                "database="+dbName+";"+
                "Integrated Security=True;"+
                "Connect Timeout=30;"+
                "Encrypt=False;"+
                "TrustServerCertificate=True;"+
                "ApplicationIntent="+WRAccess+";"+
                "MultiSubnetFailover=False;"
                );

            try
            {
                return dbConn.Open();   <-- THIS LINE REPORTING "CANNOT IMPLICITLY CONVERT 'VOID' TO 'OBJECT' 
            } catch (Exception error)
            {
                // RETURN ERROR
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You probably want to define it to return a `SqlConnection` rather than `Object` so you can use its methods and properties.  Return `null` when it fails and callers can test the result...or just create, open, use **and dispose** connections as you need them - you really dont need a helper method for that.

Comment: It looks to be that the the .Open() method is void, even changing the return method does nothing

Comment: Your code is going to need the DBConnection object so return *it* rather than result of a DBConnection method, if that is what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

To create a SQL Connection, you need to first establish SQL connectionString via VS studio In VS2017 you go into View ->Server Explorer. Within this, you will see “Data Connections” right click then add new connection: Click on the Test connection. If test connection return Okay then, click on Advance copy your connectionString which will look similar to this: 
     `Data Source=XBIRD;Initial Catalog=epos;Integrated Security=True`

Then in your code, you need to create a connectionString  in this manner 
`String conString = “Data Source=XBIRD;Initial Catalog=epos;Integrated Security=True”`
1st create an instance of object for connection string `SqlConnection con = new 
    SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"]
    .ConnectionString);`
From here onwards you should be able to connect to your database. 
Point note there are many other ways which you can connect to your database, i.e. if you are working on ASP.NET you would need to add your connection string in Web.config file and reference it in the above code. In between `[“ my connection string “]`

Help this helps, please mark the answer if it has helped you.